# Сокет клиента не подключается к серверу

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock2

Пишу простетский клиент-сервер, но почему при поптыки подключение выдает ошибку. Что я сделал не так ?

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "ws2tcpip.h"
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD Vers = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(Vers, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "YEAP" << "\n";
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addres;
    int sizeAddres = sizeof(addres);
    addres.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addres.sin_addr);
    addres.sin_port = htons(8000);
    addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SOCKET sList = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sList,(SOCKADDR*)&addres, sizeof(addres));
    listen(sList, SOMAXCONN);
    SOCKET newSock;
    newSock = accept(sList, (SOCKADDR*)&addres, &sizeAddres);
    if (newSock == 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR con.ser" << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "clint connected" << "\n";
        char msg[256] = "Hello";
        send(newSock, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
    }
```

Клиент

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include "ws2tcpip.h"
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD Vers = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(Vers, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "YEAP" << "\n";
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addres;
    int sizeAddres = sizeof(addres);
    addres.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addres.sin_addr);
    addres.sin_port = htons(8000);
    addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addres, sizeof(addres)) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "YEAP" << '\n';
    }
    char msg[256];
    recv(sock, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
    cout << msg << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Например не инициализируете переменные, неправильно проверяете успешность вызова `accept`, не получаете код ошибки.

Comment: @user7860670 ошибку выдаёт в случае клиента, а конкретно в этой части кода: if (connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addres, sizeof(addres)) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << "\n";
    }